# Conflict with django-reversion package while adding custom button in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-reversion

i am customizing django admin so i added a custom button to a model admin by "extending admin/change_list.html" template

```
    {% block object-tools-items %}
      //add custom button here
    {% endblock %}
```

it looks like this

[image]

when i added a new package [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/) for versioning of models 
which created new button for recovering data but repalced custom button which i created. I figured out that this is happening because package is also extending admin/change_list.html template and overiding object-tools-items block.

[image]

and i want some thing like this. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[You were already told the answer when you raised this "bug" on the reversion Github](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/issues/459).

> Just extend the reversion/change_list.html template with your own custom
>   template. :)

Instead of making a template with the path `admin/change_list.html` make an overriding template with the path `reversion/change_list.html`. The reason for this is that reversion does some overriding of the templates it self, so you need to make sure to play nice with those.